# oData model operation mode

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use the [Auto operation mode](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.html#.Auto) in v2 oData model.

In manifest file I have set the operation mode to "auto" and count mode to "inline".

Then on the gateway side I have added the following:

```
lv_has_inlinecount = io_tech_request_context->has_inlinecount( ).
IF   lv_has_inlinecount = abap_true.
      DESCRIBE TABLE et_entityset LINES es_response_context-inlinecount.
ENDIF.
```

But when I fetch the initial data and then sort it I would expect the sorting to happen on the client side but it keeps trigering calls to the backend.

Is there anything else that needs to be set?

Comment: As mentioned in your link what is the size of your threshold and what is the result of the count?
"If the $inlinecount is higher than the threshold, the binding will behave like in operation mode Server. In this case a new data request containing the initially set filters/sorters will be issued"

Comment: Yeah you are right its the threshold missing. I thought at first it is somehow intelligent and will decide automatically whether the filtering should happen on client side or server side.