# SAPUI5: Setting Count Mode in Manifest

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to set the Count Mode in the Manifest for sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel, and what is the syntax? I see people claiming so ( [oData model operation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738303/odata-model-operation-mode) ), but it's not documented and my trial doesn't succeed.

Regards, Niels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default count mode (as with [other settings](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#constructor)) can be defined in
`sap.ui5/models/<model name>/settings/<e.g. defaultCountMode>` inside the application descriptor

```
"models": {
  "myOdataModel": {
    "dataSource": "...",
    "settings": {
      "defaultCountMode": "InlineRepeat"
    },
    "preload": true
  }
},
```

which is also documented [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html).

> settings: Object that is passed to the model constructor

---

Here is a working example using [`InlineRepeat`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.CountMode.html) --> https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/.
If we attach a `requestSent`-handler to the corresponding ODataModel, we can observe that requests are always sent with the URL parameter `"... &$inlinecount=allpages"` appended.